# update query with st_intersects() is not finding results

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

So I am trying to identify which items from the `requests` table fall into some particular district from the `district` table using `postgis`. Basically, I am writing an `UPDATE` query that will take the district number from the `district` table and put that into the district field of the `requests` table. Here is the query that I have been using so far, but it does not return any rows.

Note that the `requests` table uses`POINT` geometry while the `district` table is a `MULTIPOLYGON`.

```
 update requests
 set req_district = districts.district
 from districts
 where st_intersects(requests.geom, districts.geom);
```

Note sure why such a simple query would not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I suppose it does the same when you simply do a select? Can you rewrite your query to include some actual geometries? Or gives us access to (part of) the data?

Comment: I wish there were a good way to bump a question. Were you ever able to resolve this?